# AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployment failed - Node 16

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a node.js (v16) app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using a pipeline with Github.

I have the following error in the log :

```
        2023/01/08 12:50:34.997432 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [check Procfile]. 
        Stop running the command. Error: node.js may have issues starting. 
        Please provide a package.json file or add server.js/app.js file in source bundle 
        2023/01/08 12:50:34.997437 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
        2023/01/08 12:50:34.997540 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0",
        "results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":
        [{"msg":"Instance deployment failed to generate a 'Procfile' for Node.js.
        Provide one of these files: 'package.json', 'server.js', or 'app.js'. The deployment failed.",
        "timestamp":1673182234997,"severity":"ERROR"},
        {"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1673182234997,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}
```

I do provide the required files :

My project structure :

```
├── public
|   ├── css
|       └──styles.css 
├── src
|   ├── app.ts
├── views
|   ├── ...
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── tsconfig.json
```

My package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongoose": "^6.8.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  },
  "name": "blog-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A basic blog",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "tsc -p . -w",
    "run": "node dist/app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/app.ts"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/InfiniteLearner/Blog-Website.git"
  },
  "author": "Infinite Learner",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/InfiniteLearner/Blog-Website/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/InfiniteLearner/Blog-Website#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.2",
    "@types/ejs": "^3.1.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.15",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.191",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "engines" : { 
    "node" : ">=16.0.0 <17.0.0"
  }

}
```

Do you think this has something to do with typescript ? Or is it something else that I am missing ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you found solution for this?